# How do I open a fragment page from notification without interacting with MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, fragment

I have written code to create a notification.

I would like the notification to directly open a fragment class called "StepsFragment".

However, whenever I click on the notification, nothing happens.
What could be the issue here?

I have tried the following solutions on Stack Overflow:

[Receive a notification issue and open a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576771/receive-a-notification-issue-and-open-a-fragment)

[How to open current fragment from notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758965/how-to-open-current-fragment-from-notification)

[Open a dialog fragment from childfragment from Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495682/open-a-dialog-fragment-from-childfragment-from-notification)

They resulted in me encountering syntax errors and I'm unable to build my project as a result.

This is the code that I used to open up a fragment from the notification.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, StepsFragment.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Steps Tracker")
                .setContentText("Steps tracked : " + input )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.steps)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1,notification);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

How do I open up the notification so that it will take me to StepsFragment instead of not doing anything when I tap on the notification?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a `Fragment` directly from an `Intent` - Fragments are attached to an `Activity`, so you will need to invoke an Activity which will then host your Fragment.

There are several ways you can achieve this. As examples, you could move `StepsFragment` into its own `Activity`, then use your `Intent` to invoke that `Activity`. Or, you can add an extra to the `Intent`, invoke `MainActivity`, and use that extra in your Activity as a hint that it should only display `StepsFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

These are the code I used to open `fragment` class when tap on the notification.

**Noted: You need to invoke Activity to call your fragment class.**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    val TAG = "FirebaseService"

    // will run when app is running foreground
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.data.size > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title, remoteMessage.notification?.body, remoteMessage.data)
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?, data: Map<String?, String>) {

        val now = Date()
        val id = Integer.parseInt(SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss", Locale.US).format(now))

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, id, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )

        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setChannelId("xxx")

        .....

        val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification)

    }
}
```

In `MainActivtiy`, override `onNewIntent` function

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        receiveIntent(intent)
    }
```

Here the `receiveIntent` function

```
fun receiveIntent(intent: Intent?) {
      // open your fragment class here
   }
```